# How to use operations based on the number of user inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am trying to make a simple calculator which tells students their average university mark based on their grades.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Renay/htm8tuo4/3/)

I'm trying to get the formula to do this: 
Step 1: (Mark * Credit Point) 
**Step 2:** Add these totals together 
**Step 3:** Get this total and divide it by the number of user inputs.

Having trouble with steps 2 and 3. 
Right now when calculate is clicked, it just appends the single answer of each row one after the other. I want to add these values then divide it by the number of inputs.(As the amount of subjects will vary between users)

Any help is really appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div>
   <table class='table'>
      <tr>
         <th> Unit Code </th>
         <th> Mark </th>
         <th> Credit Point </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td> <input type="text"></td>
          <td> <input type="text" class='mark'> </td>
          <td> <input type="text" class='creditPoint'>  </td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
          <td> <input type="text"></td>
          <td> <input type="text" class='mark'> </td>
          <td> <input type="text" class='creditPoint'> </td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> <input type="text"></td>
          <td> <input type="text" class='mark'></td>
          <td> <input type="text" class='creditPoint'> </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#wam').click(function() {
    $('.table tr').each(function() {
        var mark = $(this).find('input.mark').val();
        var cp = $(this).find('input.creditPoint').val();
        var total = ((mark * cp));
        // Find the total then divide by the number of entries

    $('body').append(total);


    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a shared variable in the loop

```
$('#wam').click(function () {
    var total = 0,
        count = 0;
    $('input.mark').each(function () {
        var mark = this.value;
        var cp = $(this).parent().next().find('input.creditPoint').val();
        var t = mark * cp || 0;//if both the fields are not entered don't add them
        if (t) {
            //if the product is 0 then don't count the value
            count++;
        }
        total += t;
    });
    $('#total').text(total);
    $('#total2').text(count ? total / count : 0);//the ternary condition to prevent division by 0

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/861uszcq/)

Comment: Such a good answer! Thank you so much for that, especially for the explanations in the comments as well. Understood it so much better.

Comment: Hey Arun, was just wondering would you know how to skip the count if the input values are '   '.
For examples if (mark && cp == ' ' ) {
     // Don't add this value to the overall count
}

Comment: The current code should exclude the sum/counting of rows where either of the 2 fields are empty.. can you give a case where it is failing

Comment: So i've altered your code a little bit because there may be some entries where a student has failed so the answer will be 0 but it still has to be included in the divisible count.
I am trying to exclude inputs that have no value at all maybe because they do not need all the rows given.
Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Renay/htm8tuo4/7/